NGINX ingress not listening custom port
Guys I'm trying to make my service accessable by domain_name with port ex: mycompany.com:8443
Is this possible? or any alternative ways to do?
But my ingress service not listening port and my service not available on mycompany.com:8443 but it's acceessable on mycompany.com
I did't change anything on Ingress its default ingress installed.
Here is my SVC and Ingress rule
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: payment-netcore-service
  namespace: develop
spec:
  selector:
    app: payment-netcore
  ports:
    - name: http
    #- protocol: TCP
      port: 8443
      targetPort: 8443
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: payment-netcore-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"

spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - pm.mycompany.com
    secretName: ssl-for-develop
  rules:
  - host: pm.mycompany.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: payment-netcore-service
            port:
              number: 8443
  - host: "www.pm.mycompany.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: payment-netcore-service
            port:
              number: 8443


As per your ingress configuration, the ingress object is listening to pm.mycompany.com and it will route traffic to the service.
Apart from this you need to have ingress controller running in the cluster.
You would also need a DNS record as pm.mycompany.com to point to the Node of the node where this service pods are running.
Once this thing is done, you should be able to ping pm.mycompany.com:8443.
Please read more about ingress here:  https://k21academy.com/docker-kubernetes/kubernetes-ingress-controllers/
